# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo // java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse, class, exception

Im new ar android and Im developing a very simple app just to practice. But I dont know why I keep getting these errors. It`s a very simple app, so I dont have no idea why its not running...

```
package com.tumta.salario;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText SalarioEdit;
Button Calcular;
TextView SalarioTotal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SalarioEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SalarioEditText);
    Calcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);
    SalarioTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SalarioTotalTextView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onCalcular(View view){
    String SalarioText = String.valueOf(SalarioEdit.getText());
    double salarioTot = Double.parseDouble(SalarioText) * 12;
    SalarioTotal.setText(String.valueOf(salarioTot));

}
```

My LOGCAT:

```
 01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tumta.salario/com.tumta.salario.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tumta.salario.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.tumta.salario-2.apk]
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tumta.salario.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.tumta.salario-2.apk]
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     at        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
01-06 14:39:09.730: E/AndroidRuntime(5538):     ... 11 more
```

Please help me!
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file also.

Answer (score 1):

Oh seriously! `public class MyActivity extends Activity!!!!!!` never extend anything else!!!! and declare your activity in manifest!(if your just created it,if not,the ide will automatically declare it by default)

Comment: Always happy to helm you:)please dont hesitate and put a mark tha t i could be useful:)thanks beforhand

Comment: Hey, I`m in another app. I have a project only for my NavigationDrawer. I`m trying to use the new drawer from lollipop, and I`m getting the same exception.. This time it has to be MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity, because it`s for the drawer.. Can u help me in this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the activity in manifest?

Comment: quick suggestion sir, make it sound like a statement or an answer so it looks like an answer.. or is that a lame suggestion? just issuing my thoughts..